# Display multiple associated array values in lists dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

This is a difficult one to know what to search for, but I've done the homework and despite how common I thought this would be, I could not find anything so I hope I can explain it ok:

I am processing a CSV file into arrays using PHP `fgetcsv`, and so I have arrays like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Australia
        [1] =>  Vic
        [2] =>  Swin
        [3] =>  Tech
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Australia
        [1] =>  Vic
        [2] =>  Monash
        [3] =>  Psych
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Australia
        [1] =>  NSW
        [2] =>  Monash
        [3] =>  Building
    )
```

I would like to build a set of lists that dynamically update based on any selection of any of the elements in the array. Ie, if you select value "Vic", it should pull out all the elements with "Vic" in item [1] - in this case would return array 0 and 1 and therefore display lists like this:

```
Country | State | Uni | Course
-------------------------------
Aus      Vic     Swin   Tech
Aus      Vic     Monash Psych
```

You should then be able to select "Uni=Swin" and get:

```
Country | State | Uni | Course
-------------------------------
Aus      Vic     Swin   Tech
```

To be honest, I'm not even sure where to start in regard to architecting this correctly for efficiency - ie, do I need to change the arrays to create associative keys that can be pulled out easily ? If so, do I need a new array for each key since I want to be able to filter them based on any of the Country, State, Uni, Course fields ?

Hope that's ok, its a little broad, but i'm sure its been done, I'm just struggling to find a nice way to structure it - I'm sure I could do it easily if I just wanted to start with the one filter, eg, Country, but I would like to make it as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more fancy way of doing it, but this is readable and gets the job done.

```
$array = [

    [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana'],
    [ 'apple', 'strawberry', 'banana']

];

function getRowsThroughElementValue($value, array $array) {
    $matched = [];

    foreach($array as $row) {
        if (!is_array($row)) {
            continue; // Not an array
        }

        if (in_array($value, $row)) {
            $matched[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $matched;
}

var_dump(getRowsThroughElementValue('apple', $array));
```

Essentially, the code loops through the first array, and then checks for the specified value in the whole `row` array. If it exists, add it to the `matched` array.

Comment: This solution will build a new array each time a list item is clicked using ajax ?

Comment: @yoyoma It will build a new array, like the other solutions. If you are worried about that taking up memory then you have nothing to worry about. It will be cleared after the request has finished due to garbage collection.

Comment: ok so in context of the page, i will have a list, when i click on an item in that list, javascript will need to call this code as ajax calls in order to filter the other lists, is that right?

Comment: Ajax will call eg. `filter-fruits.php?value=strawberry`, which will call the code above but returning the results in a friendly format such as `echo json_encode(getRowsThroughElementValue($value, $csvArray));` You can use `$_GET` to access `value` which is 'strawberry'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace 'Vic' with your search string

```
<?php
$haystack = Array(Array('Australia','Vic','Swin','Tech'),Array('Australia','Vic','Monash','Psych'),Array('Australia','NSW','Monash','Building'));
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


for($i<0;$i<count($haystack);$i++)
{
    $final_array[] = $haystack[recursive_array_search('Vic',$haystack)];    
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($final_array); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class data{

    const COUNTRY = 0;
    const STATE = 1;
    const UNI = 2;
    const COURSE = 3;

    private $csv;

    function __construct($file){

        $this->csv = fgetcsv($file);

        //$this->csv[] = array('Australia', 'Vic', 'Swin', 'Tech');
        //$this->csv[] = array('Australia', 'Vic', 'Monash', 'Psych');
        //$this->csv[] = array('Australia', 'NSW', 'Monash', 'Building');

    } 

    public function getData($type, $match) {

        $return = array();

        if (is_array($this->csv)){

            foreach ($this->csv as $key => $row){

                if (isset($row[$type])){

                    if ($row[$type] == $match){

                        $return[] = $row;

                    }

                }

            }

        }   

        return $return;

    }   

}

$data = new data('path to your file');

$rows = $data->getData($data::STATE, 'Vic');

print_r($rows);

$rows = $data->getData($data::UNI, 'Swin');

print_r($rows);
```

Comment: also like this one, very neat.  Will report back soon when I've had a chance to try them all

Comment: the line `$this->csv = fgetcsv($file);`   gives error `fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`

Comment: `$rows = $data->getData($data::STATE, 'Vic');` does not return anything

Comment: there was a typo in there somewhere i edited it.  also i didnt look at function reference for fgetcsv, assumed it was a path.  but im sure you can handle modifying it with a simple fopen("your file", "r")  ;)

Answer (score 0):

To do a lot of lookups while keeping it all in arrays, one approach is to build index arrays. These are just simple arrays keyed on a certain lookup field, with the value being a list of all the elements in your main array which match that lookup. You would have an index array for each field that you might need to do a lookup against.

So, you could build the uni index like this:

```
$uni_index = array();
foreach($main_data as $key => $value) {
    $uni = $value[2];
    if(!isset($uni_index[$uni])) {
        $uni_index[$uni] = array();
    }
    $uni_index[$uni][] = $key;
}
```

This will give you an array like this:

```
Array ( 
    [Swin] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) 
    [Monash] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) 
)
```

So if you did a lookup $uni_index['Swin'], you will get an array telling you that there is one matching result, at index 0. So $main_data[0] has all the matching data.

This allows you to do much quicker lookups. because you don't need loops after the index is set up. You're always using array keys. It can be a good approach if you want to keep everything in arrays, and will be doing a lot of lookups.

Other solutions may make sense depending on your use-case. If you will be doing occasional imports and keeping the data long-term, putting it in a database is likely to be the way to go. If you're doing a one time run with few lookups, simply looping over the array might be the best approach. But if you want to do a large number of lookups on your data in memory, then building indexes like this will make things much more efficient.

Comment: I like this one - it would be a slight hit on page load, but much quicker when making the selections in the list. I am trying to avoid using DB for this so that there is less maintenance in future - this way I let the client maintain a CSV and they don't need to get too techie.  Thx will try it soon and report back

Comment: If the index is recreated on every page load then there is no point in building an index. You would have to cache this for it to be worth your while or perform a lot of lookups. Unless the data is quite big it's an over engineered solution.

Obviously, if there is a lot of data this method makes complete sense.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the last paragraph, it might not be appropriate depending on the use-case. However, if the number of lookups is high compared to the number of lookup fields, then it will be more efficient. If you're doing a single lookup for a simple web page then it wouldn't. I think it's reasonable to consider that data for the courses across multiple universities, in multiple states of potentially multiple countries could be quite big.

Comment: hmm good points I must consider.  Am I right also in saying that this solution would assume using ajax to get the data matches - ie, you click an item in the list on the page and it refreshes all the other lists as per the matches ?

Comment: It would be the same for ajax or a standard page load - they key point is how many lookups you're doing per run. So if you were just doing one lookup to update one table, it would not make sense to index like this (unless you cache the index as @SamV mentioned). But you're updating multiple tables, and need to lookup on the same field more than once, that's when this approach will start to perform better.